Split latex page in 8 parts separated by cutting dashed lines (with scissors)
I'm a physics teacher, I would like to create flash cards for my students like this :

(the lines would be dashed lines with scissors)
Thanks!

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336742/36296 as a starting point

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722502/problem-with-flashcards-height

ye thx, i'm looking into it! I'm already reading the flashcards package to help me out, but I don't find smth useful yet :)

I'd use pgfmorepages for this sort of thing, eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60110/86

Like discussed in the comments, the original answer by Christopher Madec does compile, but with errors. It seems to be related to the usage of \AtBeginShipout{} within \flashcard{}. 
This "quick" & dirty approach does get rid of \AtBeginShipout{} and adds the desired scissors.
Code
\documentclass{scrreprt}[10pt]

\usepackage[
    paper=a4paper,
    landscape,
    right=2cm,
    left=3cm,
    marginparwidth=2cm,
    bottom=8cm,
%   showframe=true % REMARK: For debugging purposes
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

% DESCRIPTION: User settings: number of cards, color, dimensions, styles 
\def\cardsPerPage{8}

\definecolor{burgundy}{rgb}{0.7, 0.0, 0.13}

\def\cutlinesLineWidth{2mm}
\def\cutlinesDash{0.5cm}
\colorlet{cut_color}{gray}
\tikzstyle{cutlines} = [draw=cut_color, dash pattern=on \cutlinesDash off \cutlinesDash, line width=\cutlinesLineWidth]

% DESCRIPTION: Required to get grid layout
% REMARK: Number of pages has to be set manually, since \pgfpagesuselayout{}
% does not accept macro input
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]

% DESCRIPTION: Setup footer
\usepackage[nocheck]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

% Page numbering ducks
\fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,%transform shape %also possible to get smaller font
        ]
        \shuffleducks
        \duck[water=cyan!50!blue,\randomhead,
        /tikz/nodes={scale/.evaluated={\value{page}>99?0.4:0.6},font=\bfseries}, 
        signpost=\scalebox{4}{
            \parbox{6cm}{\hspace{-0.3em}\color{black}
                \centering\thepage}}, signback =white]
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% DESCRIPTION: Required for dashed frame 
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} % REMARK: Required for scissors symbol

% DESCRIPTION: Place the scissors on odd (left) cards
\newcommand{\scissorsCardLeft}[1][1]{%
    % DESCRIPTION: Only if not penultimate/last card on page, add horizontal scissor 
    \ifnum#1<1\relax%
        \node[text=cut_color] at ([xshift=-0.0625cm,yshift=0.25em]current page.south){\scalebox{5}{\faCut}};%
    \fi%
    \node[text=cut_color] at ([xshift=-0.25em,yshift=-0.2cm]current page.east){\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{5}{\faCut}}};
}

% DESCRIPTION: Place the scissors on even (right) cards
\newcommand{\scissorsCardRight}{%
    \node[text=cut_color] at ([xshift=-0.0625cm,yshift=0.25em]current page.south){\scalebox{5}{\faCut}};
}

\newcommand{\cutlines}[1][\thepage]{%
    % DESCRIPTION: Calculate all the boolean conditions
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\evenOdd}{int(Mod(\thepage,2))}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\penultimateCardOnPage}{int(Mod(#1,\cardsPerPage-1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastCardOnPage}{int(Mod(#1,\cardsPerPage))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastTwoCardsOnPage}{or(\penultimateCardOnPage==0, \lastCardOnPage==0)}
    
    % DESCRIPTION: Set cutlines according to page properties
    % Step 1: Is page even/odd = left/right
    \ifnum\evenOdd=1\relax%
        % DESCRIPTION: If page is odd (left):
        % Step 2: Is card one of the last two cards on page
        \ifnum\lastTwoCardsOnPage=1\relax%
            % DESCRIPTION: If card is one of the last two cards on page, only draw cut line on the right
            \draw[cutlines]([xshift=-\cutlinesLineWidth/2,yshift= 0mm]current page.south east)-|([xshift=-\cutlinesLineWidth/2,yshift=0mm]current page.north east);%
            \scissorsCardLeft[\lastTwoCardsOnPage]%
        \else%
            % DESCRIPTION: If card is not one of the last two cards on page, draw cut line on the bottom and right
            \draw[cutlines]([xshift=0cm,yshift= \cutlinesLineWidth/2]current page.south west)-|([xshift=-\cutlinesLineWidth/2,yshift=0mm]current page.north east);%
            \scissorsCardLeft[\lastTwoCardsOnPage]%
        \fi%
    \else%
        % DESCRIPTION: If page is even (right)
        % Step 2: Is card one of the last two cards on page
        \ifnum\lastTwoCardsOnPage=0\relax%
            % DESCRIPTION: If card is not one of the last two cards on page, draw cut line on the bottom and right
            \draw[cutlines]([xshift=0cm, yshift=\cutlinesLineWidth/2]current page.south west)--([xshift=0cm, yshift=\cutlinesLineWidth/2]current page.south east);%
            \scissorsCardRight%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\sidePanelLeft}[1][0]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pagenumberCorrected}{\thepage-#1*\cardsPerPage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            % DESCRIPTION: Left side panel
            \draw[fill,color=white!40!burgundy]%
            ([xshift=1cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.north west);
            \node [rotate=90] at ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.west) {\bfseries\resizebox{!}{0.6cm}{\color{white}{\LeftSideText}}};%
            
            % DESCRIPTION: Cutlines
            \cutlines[\pagenumberCorrected]
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centering
    {\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont #1}
    \vspace*{\fill}
}

\newcommand{\flashcardFront}[2][]{%
    #1
    \sidePanelLeft
    \question{#2}%
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\grid}{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \ClearShipoutPicture
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pagenumberCorrected}{int(mod(\thepage, \cardsPerPage))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\evenOdd}{int(mod(\pagenumberCorrected, 2))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\isTop}{%
            int(or(\pagenumberCorrected == 1, \pagenumberCorrected == 2))%
        }
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \draw[step=1cm,white!90!gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
            \cutlines[\pagenumberCorrected]%
            
            % DESCRIPTION: Add additional scissors to cover up grid
            % DESCRIPTION: Top; determine whether on top of page or not
            \ifnum\isTop=0\relax%
                \node[text=cut_color] at ([xshift=-0.0625cm,yshift=0.25em]current page.north){\scalebox{5}{\faCut}};%
            \fi%
            
            % DESCRIPTION: card even (right), side left
            % DESCRIPTION: Only when not odd (left) card
            \ifnum\evenOdd=0\relax%
                \node[text=cut_color] 
                at ([xshift=-0.25em,yshift=-0.2cm]current page.west){
                    \rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{5}{\faCut}}
                };
            \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \phantom{bla}
    \newpage
}

\begin{document}
    % Création bande verticale chapitre colorée
    \def\LeftSideText{Électromagnétisme - Chapitre 3 : Magnétostatique}
    
    %begin novalidate
    \flashcardFront{À quoi reconnaît-on une carte de lignes de champ magnétique ? En particulier, comment repérer d'éventuelles sources du champ et leur signe/sens ?}
    \flashcardFront{Donner, sans démonstration, le champ magnétique créé par un fil infiniment fin.}
    \flashcardFront{Donner 3 ODG de champs magnétostatiques.}
    \flashcardFront{\'Enoncer le théorème d'Ampère.}
    \flashcardFront{Définir la densité volumique d'énergie magnétique.}
    \flashcardFront{Donner, sans démonstration, le champ magnétique créé par un solénoïde infini.}
    \flashcardFront{\'Enoncer les équations de Maxwell reliées au champ magnétostatique.}
    \flashcardFront{Qu'est ce qu'un dipôle magnétostatique ? Définir le moment magnétique d'un tel dipôle.}
%   %%end novalidate
    
    \grid\grid\grid\grid\grid\grid\grid\grid
    
\end{document}

Result


Why is it a "quick" and dirty solution?

usage of \phantom{} to create a non-empty page
placing more elements than needed to cover up artifacts (scissors on back of card); however, should be ok, since the main focus of this document is to be printed out and not be processed digitally
number in \pgfpageuselayout{} is hard coded
a lot of manual, repetitive work required to get it all typeset correctly; perhaps one should try to automate it further or experiment with the flashcards package


Well, thanks for this long and complete answer! I was trying to solve the problem and add cutlines, but you answered :)

I wasn't able to put scissors, but this is what I made for my flashcards (if someone wants to use this code!)
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,
   landscape,
   right=2cm,
   left=3cm,
   marginparwidth=2cm,
   bottom=8cm,
}
\usepackage[nocheck]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%Page numbering ducks
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\fancyfoot[C]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,%transform shape %also possible to get smaller font
   ]
\shuffleducks
\duck[water=cyan!50!blue,\randomhead,
/tikz/nodes={scale/.evaluated={\value{page}>99?0.4:0.6},font=\bfseries}, 
signpost=\scalebox{4}{
\parbox{6cm}{\hspace{-0.3em}\color{black}
\centering\thepage}}, signback =white]
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% Séparation en 8 entités (donc du A7)
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \dashbox{20pt}(\paperwidth,\paperheight){}% From showframe.sty
  }%
}

% Couleurs sidebar
\definecolor{burgundy}{rgb}{0.7, 0.0, 0.13}

\begin{document}
% Création bande verticale chapitre colorée
\def\LeftSideText{Électromagnétisme - Chapitre 3 : Magnétostatique}
\newcommand{\LeftSideBar}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill,color=white!40!burgundy]
([xshift=1cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.north west);
\node [rotate=90] at ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.west) {\bfseries\resizebox{!}{0.6cm}{\color{white}{\LeftSideText}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
}% 

% Commande création grid
\newcommand{\grid}{
   \thispagestyle{empty}
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[step=1cm,white!90!gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (29.7,21);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \phantom{bla}
    \newpage
}
% Repeat grid
\newcommand{\Repeat}[2]{% \repeat already defined
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{#2}
}

% Commande création question
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
{\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont #1}
\vspace*{\fill}
}

% Commande création flashcard
\newcommand{\flashcard}[1]{
\AtBeginShipout{\LeftSideBar}

\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
{\fontsize{35}{42}\selectfont #1}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
}

%%begin novalidate
% For some reason, there's an error here, but the compiles still works % (at least on Overleaf)
\flashcard{À quoi reconnaît-on une carte de lignes de champ magnétique ? En particulier, comment repérer d'éventuelles sources du champ et leur signe/sens ?}
\flashcard{Donner, sans démonstration, le champ magnétique créé par un fil infiniment fin.}
\flashcard{Donner 3 ODG de champs magnétostatiques.}
\flashcard{\'Enoncer le théorème d'Ampère.}
\flashcard{Définir la densité volumique d'énergie magnétique.}
\flashcard{Donner, sans démonstration, le champ magnétique créé par un solénoïde infini.}
\flashcard{\'Enoncer les équations de Maxwell reliées au champ magnétostatique.}
\flashcard{Qu'est ce qu'un dipôle magnétostatique ? Définir le moment magnétique d'un tel dipôle.}
%%end novalidate

\Repeat{8}{\grid} 

\end{document}




Could you please verify/improve the MWE you posted? It compiles with many errors, stating that some subcommand in\flashcard{} is not defined. Additionally, you seem to load many packages that are not used and overwrite some geometry settings.

Yes sure, I'm compiling it in overleaf, I haven't figured the subcommand problem yet

It seems to be related to the \AtBeginShipout{} macro in the definition of \flashcard{}. Not sure why this causes problems, because from what I can gather from the manual, it should work.

Yeah, I checked almost every line, and removed almost everything, the error still persists
